# geom_lollipop (package Ggalt) not working

Tags: r, ggalt

I am following the tutorial on how to use `geom_lollipop`, from the package `ggalt` at the following [link](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/ggalt).

The code I am trying to run is the following:

```
df <- read.csv(text="category,pct
Other,0.09
               South Asian/South Asian Americans,0.12
               Interngenerational/Generational,0.21
               S Asian/Asian Americans,0.25
               Muslim Observance,0.29
               Africa/Pan Africa/African Americans,0.34
               Gender Equity,0.34
               Disability Advocacy,0.49
               European/European Americans,0.52
               Veteran,0.54
               Pacific Islander/Pacific Islander Americans,0.59
               Non-Traditional Students,0.61
               Religious Equity,0.64
               Caribbean/Caribbean Americans,0.67
               Latino/Latina,0.69
               Middle Eastern Heritages and Traditions,0.73
               Trans-racial Adoptee/Parent,0.76
               LBGTQ/Ally,0.79
               Mixed Race,0.80
               Jewish Heritage/Observance,0.85
               International Students,0.87", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, sep=",", header=TRUE)


library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(ggalt)


gg <- ggplot(df, aes(y=reorder(category, pct), x=pct))
gg <- gg + geom_lollipop(point.colour="steelblue", point.size=3, horizontal=TRUE)
gg <- gg + scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0), labels=percent,
                              breaks=seq(0, 1, by=0.2), limits=c(0, 1))
gg <- gg + labs(x=NULL, y=NULL, 
                title="SUNY Cortland Multicultural Alumni survey results")
gg <- gg + theme_minimal(base_family="Arial Narrow")
gg <- gg + theme(panel.grid.major.y=element_blank())
gg <- gg + theme(panel.grid.minor=element_blank())
gg <- gg + theme(axis.line.y=element_line(color="#2b2b2b", size=0.15))
gg <- gg + theme(axis.text.y=element_text(margin=margin(r=-5, l=0)))
gg <- gg + theme(plot.margin=unit(rep(30, 4), "pt"))
gg <- gg + theme(plot.title=element_text(face="bold"))
gg
```

Instead of creating a lollipop plot, my output is the following:
[image: lollipop]

It appears that `geom_lollipop` is not working. Also when I try to digit geom_lollipop, Rstudio does not seem to find it among the available functions.

I thought it was a problem of package version, but I have updated R and reinstalled all the packages above. Following the versions of R and libraries in use:

```
> packageVersion("ggalt")
[1] ‘0.1.1’
> packageVersion("ggplot2")
[1] ‘2.1.0’
> packageVersion("scales")
[1] ‘0.4.0’
> R.version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0   
arch           x86_64                      
os             darwin13.4.0                
system         x86_64, darwin13.4.0        
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          3.1                         
year           2016                        
month          06                          
day            21                          
svn rev        70800                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
nickname       Bug in Your Hair
```

Any idea why this is not working?

Comment: works for me with `ggalt_0.3.0.9000 scales_0.4.0     ggplot2_2.1.0` (maybe you need Github/devel version?  try `devtools::install_github("hrbrmstr/ggalt")` ...

Comment: the exact same code (first block) works for me (the pkg author). perhaps try also doing `devtools::install_github("hadley/ggplot2")`

Comment: @BenBolker yep it seems to be working with the devel version! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(updated from comment)

Works for me with `ggalt_0.3.0.9000 scales_0.4.0 ggplot2_2.1.0`.

Maybe you need the Github/devel version? Try restarting session/unloading `ggalt`, then

```
devtools::install_github("hrbrmstr/ggalt")
```

and reload the package.